# WordPress Customizer API (Kirki) - Repeater Image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

I'll try and explain this as best I can.

First, I'm using [a toolkit called Kirki](https://aristath.github.io/kirki/) to extend the WordPress Customizer API

What I have is a section within my theme that contains a 4 column layout of services. Each of these services has a icon.
I am using the repeater field to allow users to edit each of these. I have no issues except when it comes to the image...

By default, there are already 4 columns made and filled with content, including images. 
The exact issue is with displaying the images, either I can display the image using

```
<?php $img_url = esc_url_raw($setting['service_image']); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="...">
```

Which allows the default image to display perfectly fine, however if the user uploads their own image, it breaks and wont output a url. Rather it outputs the ID.

To rememdy that, I can change

```
<?php $img_url = esc_url_raw($setting['service_image']); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($setting['service_image']); ?>
```

which will output the user uploaded image, however that causes the default image to now be broken, and output nothing but a broken image with a blank src.

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that it will both display the default image, and when the user uploads their own image, replace it with the one they have uploaded.

I've tried everything I can think of but haven't managed to figure it out.

In the event you need more of the code...

## **Kirki Config**

```
// Panels and Sections
Kirki::add_panel( 'pestex_theme_settings', array(
       'priority'    => 10,
       'title'       => __( 'Theme Customization', 'pestex' ),
       'description' => __( 'Customization Options', 'pestex' ),
    ) );


//Nesting Section Inside Panel Above
Kirki::add_section( 'pestex_services_styles', array(
       'title'          => __( 'Section One - Services Styles' ),
       'panel'          => 'pestex_theme_settings', 
       'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    ) );




// Repeater Setting
Kirki::add_field( 'pestex_section_one_services_control', array(
    'type'        => 'repeater',
    'label'       => esc_attr__( 'Services', 'pestex' ),
    'section'     => 'pestex_services_styles',
    'priority'    => 10,
    'choices' => array(
    'limit' => 4
    ),
    'row_label' => array(
        'type'  => 'field',
        'value' => esc_attr__('service', 'pestex' ),
        'field' => 'link_text',
    ),
    'settings'    => 'pestex_section_one_services',
    // Defining Pre-Made Repeater Fields
    'default'     => array(
        array(  
            //Default Image/Fields
            'service_image' =>  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/resicon.svg',
            'service_title' => esc_attr__( 'Residential', 'pestex' ),
            'service_text'  => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit et, consectet adipiscing elit. Cras ut dictum.',
        ),
        array(
            //Default Image/Fields
            'service_image' =>  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/comicon.svg',
            'service_title' => esc_attr__( 'Commercial', 'pestex' ),
            'service_text'  => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit et, consectet adipiscing elit. Cras ut dictum.',
        ),
        array(
            //Default Image/Fields
            'service_image' =>  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/inspicon.svg',
            'service_title' => esc_attr__( 'Free Inspection', 'pestex' ),
            'service_text'  => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit et, consectet adipiscing elit. Cras ut dictum.',
        ),
        array(
            //Default Image/Fields
            'service_image' =>  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/ecoicon.svg',
            'service_title' => esc_attr__( 'Eco-Friendly', 'pestex' ),
            'service_text'  => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit et, consectet adipiscing elit. Cras ut dictum.',
        ),
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'service_image' => array(
            'type'        => 'image',
            'label'       => esc_attr__( 'Service Icon', 'pestex' ),
            'default'     =>  '',
        ),
        'service_title' => array(
            'type'        => 'text',
            'label'       => esc_attr__( 'Service Title', 'pestex' ),
            'description' => esc_attr__( 'This will be the title of your service', 'pestex' ),
            'default'     => '',
        ),
        'service_text' => array(
            'type'        => 'textarea',
            'label'       => esc_attr__( 'Service Text', 'pestex' ),
            'description' => esc_attr__( 'This will be the text displayed below the service title', 'pestex' ),
            'default'     => '',
        ),
    )
) );
```

## **HTML/CSS**

```
// Grabbing Kirki Repeater Field and Assigning Variable 
$settings = get_theme_mod( 'pestex_section_one_services' ); ?>

<?php foreach( $settings as $setting ) : ?>

// Calling Image from Repeater Field and Assigning Variable
<?php $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($setting['service_image']); ?>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">

        //Displaying Image          
        <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="#">

        <h3><?php echo $setting['service_title']; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $setting['service_text']; ?></p>
     </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I'm 100% sure you've tried this, but have to ask anyway, can you use an IF statement in the PHP to switch between the 2 working instances of the code above? Check for an uploaded image and if it doesn't exist use the code that displays the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Solved**

After the response from @Asher, I looked into finding a way I could find a way to check to see if the image was uploaded to the media library or not, and then assign it the proper settings... (Which for some reason I never thought of, I had tried checking some other things but never to see if the image was uploaded to the media library) and I ended up running across this function: `wp_attachment_is_image()`

Using this I was able to get it to do what I needed with the following code

```
if ( ! wp_attachment_is_image( $setting['service_image'] ) ){

    $img_url = esc_url_raw($setting['service_image']);

} else {

    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($setting['service_image']);
}
```